# Chrome crashes after 30-40 minutes

Tags: signalr

We currently have a live data feed implemented with SignalR.  However, in Chrome (we currently have only observed this behaviour in chrome) crashes after 30-40 minutes of activity and the chrome kill pages dialogue appears.  In order to start receiving reads again we have to click kill page and relogin to the application.

Has any one else observed this behaviour with long running feeds?

Answer (score 0):

We haven't seen any bug reports related to this.  However, if you can provide a sample or concrete steps (via https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues) that reproduces the issue consistently we can check it out.